# How to dynamically add panels depending upon database result

Tags: c#, sql

How can I dynamically add panels and some controls in it depending upon results I get from database.
[image]

I want to to display the results of this datagridview in the panels but the panels should be added dynamically next to each other depending upon the results. Like I have 3 results in datagridview so there should be 3 panels added dynamically. Please advice.

Comment: Is the "thing" on the left the panel you're talking about?

Comment: @Haytam Yes it's a template panel I added

Comment: And where would you like the other panels to be? Cuz I don't see space for the others.. Also please provide some code (e.g. how do you fill the datagridview)

Comment: Datagridview will be replaced by new panels. I just added the datagridview to help visualize the problem. The template panel will also be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `SqlConnection` to perform a `SELECT` command and get the rows you want and for each row add a custom panel with the row's information.
I would also advise you to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` so that it handles spacing/location for you.

In your `Form_Load`:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection informations here");
conn.Open();

var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from YourTable", conn);

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Pass the useful informations to your panel
        var pnl = new MyCustomPanel(reader["Id"].ToString(), reader["Property_Type1"].ToString());
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pnl);
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

And your custom control's contructor should like something like this, where you set values of your panel's controls for each row:

```
public MyCustomPanel(string id, string propertyType1)
{
    txtId.Text = id;
    txtPropertyType1.Text = propertyType1;
}
```